# awstats not parse logformat OS, mobile browsers, robots, keyworks

Tags: apache, awstats

I have my Apache configure with logfomat in **combined** pattern:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
```

This sample out from result log:

```
192.168.201.156 - - [02/Feb/2013:00:00:10 -0430] "GET /conseme/styles/datePicker.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://myserver.com.com:49004/conseme/iniciar.do?APP_CODE=ICA&pms=9eew1896ugjew8SxfYG2s8XxdYML4qZAVEX4lbkZUGo&aux=SM010213235332219&incrustado=1&usession=6172996210449710866&mainappcode=PORTPROV" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
192.168.201.156 - - [02/Feb/2013:00:00:11 -0430] "GET /conseme/styles/calendario.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://myserver.com.com:49004/conseme/iniciar.do?APP_CODE=ICA&pms=9eew1896ugjew8SxfYG2s8XxdYML4qZAVEX4lbkZUGo&aux=SM010213235332219&incrustado=1&usession=6172996210449710866&mainappcode=PORTPROV" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
192.168.201.156 - - [02/Feb/2013:00:00:11 -0430] "GET /conseme/styles/windows_modal.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://myserver.com.com:49004/conseme/iniciar.do?APP_CODE=ICA&pms=9eew1896ugjew8SxfYG2s8XxdYML4qZAVEX4lbkZUGo&aux=SM010213235332219&incrustado=1&usession=6172996210449710866&mainappcode=PORTPROV" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
192.168.201.156 - - [02/Feb/2013:00:00:11 -0430] "GET /conseme/styles/confirm.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://myserver.com.com:49004/conseme/iniciar.do?APP_CODE=ICA&pms=9eew1896ugjew8SxfYG2s8XxdYML4qZAVEX4lbkZUGo&aux=SM010213235332219&incrustado=1&usession=6172996210449710866&mainappcode=PORTPROV" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
192.168.201.156 - - [02/Feb/2013:00:00:11 -0430] "GET /conseme/js/jquery/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://myserver.com.com:49004/conseme/iniciar.do?APP_CODE=ICA&pms=9eew1896ugjew8SxfYG2s8XxdYML4qZAVEX4lbkZUGo&aux=SM010213235332219&incrustado=1&usession=6172996210449710866&mainappcode=PORTPROV" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
192.168.201.156 - - [02/Feb/2013:00:00:11 -0430] "GET /conseme/js/jquery/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://myserver.com.com:49004/conseme/iniciar.do?APP_CODE=ICA&pms=9eew1896ugjew8SxfYG2s8XxdYML4qZAVEX4lbkZUGo&aux=SM010213235332219&incrustado=1&usession=6172996210449710866&mainappcode=PORTPROV" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
192.168.201.156 - - [02/Feb/2013:00:00:12 -0430] "GET /conseme/js/calendario/date.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://myserver.com.com:49004/conseme/iniciar.do?APP_CODE=ICA&pms=9eew1896ugjew8SxfYG2s8XxdYML4qZAVEX4lbkZUGo&aux=SM010213235332219&incrustado=1&usession=6172996210449710866&mainappcode=PORTPROV" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
192.168.201.156 - - [02/Feb/2013:00:00:12 -0430] "GET /conseme/js/calendario/jquery.datepicker.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://myserver.com.com:49004/conseme/iniciar.do?APP_CODE=ICA&pms=9eew1896ugjew8SxfYG2s8XxdYML4qZAVEX4lbkZUGo&aux=SM010213235332219&incrustado=1&usession=6172996210449710866&mainappcode=PORTPROV" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
192.168.201.156 - - [02/Feb/2013:00:00:12 -0430] "GET /conseme/js/jquery.maskedinput.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://myserver.com.com:49004/conseme/iniciar.do?APP_CODE=ICA&pms=9eew1896ugjew8SxfYG2s8XxdYML4qZAVEX4lbkZUGo&aux=SM010213235332219&incrustado=1&usession=6172996210449710866&mainappcode=PORTPROV" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
192.168.201.156 - - [02/Feb/2013:00:00:13 -0430] "GET /conseme/js/Validador.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://myserver.com.com:49004/conseme/iniciar.do?APP_CODE=ICA&pms=9eew1896ugjew8SxfYG2s8XxdYML4qZAVEX4lbkZUGo&aux=SM010213235332219&incrustado=1&usession=6172996210449710866&mainappcode=PORTPROV" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
192.168.202.244 - - [02/Feb/2013:00:00:13 -0430] "GET /portalasegurado/3/BOTPAGO/50/50.10/opcion.do HTTP/1.1" 200 1837 "http://myserver.com.com:49004/portalasegurado/menu.do" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB6; BTRS129265; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; AskTbBCPA/5.14.1.20007; 89770703; compat/4.1.08010)"
192.168.202.244 - - [02/Feb/2013:00:00:13 -0430] "GET /portalasegurado/styles/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1228 "http://myserver.com.com:49004/portalasegurado/3/BOTPAGO/50/50.10/opcion.do" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB6; BTRS129265; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; AskTbBCPA/5.14.1.20007; 89770703; compat/4.1.08010)"
192.168.201.156 - - [02/Feb/2013:00:00:13 -0430] "GET /conseme/js/validation.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://myserver.com.com:49004/conseme/iniciar.do?APP_CODE=ICA&pms=9eew1896ugjew8SxfYG2s8XxdYML4qZAVEX4lbkZUGo&aux=SM010213235332219&incrustado=1&usession=6172996210449710866&mainappcode=PORTPROV" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
192.168.202.244 - - [02/Feb/2013:00:00:13 -0430] "GET /portalasegurado/js/jquery/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 26048 "http://myserver.com.com:49004/portalasegurado/3/BOTPAGO/50/50.10/opcion.do" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB6; BTRS129265; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; AskTbBCPA/5.14.1.20007; 89770703; compat/4.1.08010)"
192.168.201.156 - - [02/Feb/2013:00:00:13 -0430] "GET /conseme/js/interfaz.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://myserver.com.com:49004/conseme/iniciar.do?APP_CODE=ICA&pms=9eew1896ugjew8SxfYG2s8XxdYML4qZAVEX4lbkZUGo&aux=SM010213235332219&incrustado=1&usession=6172996210449710866&mainappcode=PORTPROV" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
```

The logformat for awstats is same as the config file sample:

```
LogFormat = "%host %other %logname %time1 %methodurl %code %bytesd %refererquot %uaquot"
```

This match perfect with apache output and the **ACCURACY SETUP SECTION** *(robots, browsers, os, referers, file types) detection* have value 2 for each property. I try test with LevelForBrowsersDetection=allphones and no work for mobile browsers detection

I run awstats.pl to build database:

```
perl C:\mysoft\awstats-7.1\wwwroot\cgi-bin\awstats.pl -config=www.myserver.com -lang=en -staticlinks -update -month=2 -year=2013 ^
LogFile="C:\mysoft\awstats-7.1\tools\logresolvemerge.pl -showsteps C:\temp\awstats\log\2013\02\* |"
```

Next run builstatic_pages to generate html full report

```
perl C:\mysoft\awstats-7.1\tools\awstats_buildstaticpages.pl -awstatsprog=C:\mysoft\awstats-7.1\wwwroot\cgi-bin\awstats.pl ^
-config=www.myserver.com -lang=en -staticlinks -output -month=2 -year=2013 -dir=.\stats\2013\02  1>awstats_buildstaticpages_last_execution.log
```

All this run OK but in the Main HTML page the sections:

- **OS**: only show **Unknown**
- **Browsers**: no detect mobile/phones and versions, show Unknown for all diference to IE, Safari, Chrome, FF and Opera.
- **Links from an Internet Search Engine**: is empty. Look at the log and there are references from Google and others.
- **Search Keyphrases**: empty
- **Search Keywords**: empty

My system enviroment is:
 - Windows 7 64b and test on Windows Server 2003 32b
 - ActivePerl-5.16.2.1602-MSWin32-x86-296513
 - Awstats-7.1

I try to find on internet issues related unsuccessfully.

Please let me know any idea, is important for my the mobile browsers and OS family/types.
Thanks

Comment: sad there is no solution.  I share the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a perl version higher than 5.12.4 and awstats lower or equal than 7.1, you currently will lose statistics for OS and search engine detection.

Then 2 solutions :

- downgrade perl
- upgrade awstats to >=7.1.1

See :

- Bug report http://sourceforge.net/p/awstats/discussion/43430/thread/455f24ce/
- Awstats change log : http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_changelog.txt